# parsing nested function calls

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Im trying to parse some C++ code using grammars from the github repository https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4 .

The problem I have is for parsing nested function calls, for example,

```
int main()
{
    foo(bar(test()));
    return 0;
}
```

How can I differentiate between a simple function call like `foo(1);` and nested function calls like in the example above?

NOTE: Im parsing C++ using C++.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use [grammars-v4/cpp](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/cpp), make sure that your input to the parser is output from the C++ preprocessor (`g++ -E file.cc`). The grammar cannot parse code that contains macros.

To find the functions that call some nested function, you will want to find postfix_expression corresponding to the following XPath2 expression: `//postfix_expression[expression_list//postfix_expression//Identifier]`. In English, you will want to find postfix_expression nodes that contains an immediate expression_list child that contains a postfix_expression that contains an Identifier.

This is easy to implement using my [Trash toolkit for Antlr4 parsing](https://github.com/kaby76/Domemtech.Trash). It implements XPath2 searching in Antlr4 parse trees. Or, you can do this by writing an Antlr4 visitor that traverses a parse tree, starting at an Identifier terminal node then goes up the tree looking for postfix_expression/expression_list/postfix_expression in the parent chain.

So, for your input, using the command `trparse tst.txt | trxgrep ' //postfix_expression[expression_list//postfix_expression//Identifier]' | trtext`, the output is:

```
bar(test())
foo(bar(test()))
```

Note, the cpp grammar is only good for the Java target. I have a port to C#, which is a requirement for Trash. Let me know if you need that grammar.

Comment: "you can do this by writing an Antlr4 visitor that traverses a parse tree, starting at an Identifier terminal node then goes up the tree looking for postfix_expression/expression_list/postfix_expression in the parent chain.

So, for your input, using the command trparse tst.txt | trxgrep ' //postfix_expression[expression_list//postfix_expression//Identifier]' | trtext, the output is:"